# Bareiss algorithm vs. LU-decomposition

Tags: matrix, matrix-factorization

I at the moment try to fully understand the Bareiss algorithm for calculating determinants. 
One question that came to my mind is the following:
Why is LU-decomposition much more often used than the Bareiss algorithm?
I mean, they both have a complexity of $\mathcal{O}{(n^3)}$, so what's the problem with Bareiss?

Comment: Note that Bareiss is for calculating the determinant of an **integer** matrix by using only **integer arithmetic**.

Comment: So LU-decomposition is used to be able to also calculate determinants of complex matrices?

Comment: I believe at least `scipy.linalg.lu` could handle complex matrices as well.

Comment: Between integers and complex numbers there are real numbers, which are by far the most common case in practice.

Comment: I know, but I don't really get the comment of @AloneProgrammer, because bareiss works fine with real numbers.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Bareiss' algorithm is a better choice if you have to compute exactly determinants of integer matrices, as noted in the comments.

When it comes to real (floating-point) or complex matrices, the main point to understand is that **computing determinants is not a common task**. In scientific computing, determinants are often a wrong choice: whatever you wish to do, there is usually a faster and more stable choice that does not involve them. Want to know if a matrix is singular or find its rank? Use SVD or RRQR. Want to solve linear systems? Use LU, not Cramer's rule. Want to compute eigenvalues? Use the QR/Francis algorithm, not the characteristic polynomial.

Moreover, overflow and underflow are often practical issues that discourage the use of determinants (exercise: use your favorite programming language to compute $\det(0.1 I_{350\times 350})$). See also [this answer of mine](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1999792/65548) on [math.se], which has similar arguments.

So there is little interest in their computation. LU is more used because it does much more than computing the determinant, and typically that "much more" is the reason you wanted to compute a determinant in the first place. Bareiss algorithm, as far as I understand, is a "one-trick pony algorithm": it computes the determinant, and that's it.

So it is not surprising that when you asked a question about determinants on this site the very first comment you got was "But, what do you *really* need it for?". :)

Answer (score 2):

While LU can do be used as a tool to do a lot more, most implementations use floating point math, which inherently introduces inaccuracies.

I have tested Bareiss algorithm on an integer-normalised matrix vs Gauss with a custom fraction class for calculating the exact determinant of a matrix and the Bareiss algorithm was roughly twice as fast as the Gauss (in python). This due to the overhead of creating fraction objects vs using built-in integers.

What I did find was:

1. Gauss is much more well documented with examples - that makes it easier to implement quickly
2. Bareiss is actually just as simple, if not more simple as an algorithm - both wikipedia (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bareiss_algorithm#The_algorithm) and this question (https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/124759/determinant-calculation-bareiss-vs-gauss-algorithm) have great defintions
3. You need to be sure that your data will not lead to overruns when normalised to integers or handle this case with a `try: except:` block or an initial data analysis and a fall back solution (eg Gauss with fractions)
4. Most python libraries are not optimised for speed as no one can beat numpy, if you are happy with floating point results. E.g.: my set up with my own fraction and matrix classes came out a factor 10-100 faster for my use cases than SymPy with its rational and matrix classes. Although it is certainly not yet as robust or generically usable.

Here's my implementation:
The normalisation of the matrix *& de-normalisation of the determinant*:

```
    def det(self, ver=None):
        versions = {
            "naive": self._det_naive,
            "triangular": self._det_triangular,
            "bareiss": self._det_bareiss,
            "no_calc": self._det_nocalc
        }

        if ver == None:
            values = [v for v in chain(*self.rows)]
            if False in {isint for isint in map(isinstance, values, [int for i in range(len(values))])}:
                if not False in {isIntOrFraction for isIntOrFraction in map(isinstance, values, [(int, fraction) for i in range(len(values))])}:
                    #have only ints and fractions
                    f = {x for x in values if type(x) == fraction}
                    lcd = fraction.lcd(f)
                    Normalised = matrix([[int(f * lcd) for f in s] for s in self.rows])
                    d = Normalised.det("bareiss")
                    for i in range (self.rowcount):
                        d = fraction(d,lcd)
                    self.D = d
                    ver = "no_calc"
                else:
                    #have something that is not an int or a fractions
                    ver = "triangular"
            else:
                #have only ints
                ver = "bareiss"

        return versions[ver]()
```

`fraction.lcd()` returns the lowest common denominator of a list or tuple of fractions.
`fraction(n,d)` returns a simplified fraction with numerator *n* and denominator *d*

The Bareiss algorithm:

```
    def _det_bareiss(self):
        if self.D == None:
            twin = array2d(self.rows)
            Df = 1
            for k in range(twin.rowcount-1):
                Df *= twin.pivot(k)
                if Df == 0: #No pivot found -> Determinant is zero
                    self.D = 0
                    break
                for i in range(k+1, twin.rowcount):
                    for j in range(k+1, twin.colcount):
                        k_1k_1 = 1 if k == 0 else twin[k-1,k-1]
                        twin[i,j] = ((twin[i,j] * twin[k,k]) - (twin[i,k] * twin[k,j]))//k_1k_1
            self.D = Df * twin[self.rowcount-1,self.colcount-1]
        return self.D
```

and the pivot function:

```
    def pivot(self, k):
        Df = 1
        if sum(map(abs,self.columns[k][k:])) == 0: #there is no suitable pivot row ...
            if sum(map(abs,self.rows[k][k:])) != 0: #but there is a column to the right which is non-zero
                pivotcol = min(
                    [(j,c) for j,c in
                        enumerate(
                            [
                                sum([1 for x in col[k:] if x != 0])
                                for col in self.columns[k:]
                            ]
                        )
                        if c > 0
                    ],
                    key = (lambda enum: enum[1])
                )[0] + k
                self.swapcols(k, pivotcol) #so let's bring one of them over and then find the right pivot row
                Df *= -1
            else:
                return 0 #this col has all zeros in it - Determinant is zero

        pivotrow = min(
            [(i, c) for i,c in
                enumerate(
                    [
                        sum([1 for x in row[k:] if x != 0 and row[k] != 0])
                        for row in self.rows[k:]
                    ]
                ) 
                if c > 0
            ],
            key = (lambda enum: enum[1])
        )[0] + k

        if pivotrow != k:
            self.swaprows(k, pivotrow)
            Df *= -1

        return Df

    def swapcols(self,c1,c2):
        for i in range(self.rowcount):
            self.values[i,c1], self.values[i, c2] = self.values[i, c2], self.values[i, c1]
            self.rows[i][c1], self.rows[i][c2] = self.rows[i][c2], self.rows[i][c1]
        self.columns[c1], self.columns[c2] = self.columns[c2], self.columns[c1]


    def swaprows(self,r1,r2):
        for j in range(self.colcount):
            self.values[r1,j], self.values[r2,j] = self.values[r2,j], self.values[r1,j]
            self.columns[j][r1], self.columns[j][r2] = self.columns[j][r2], self.columns[j][r1] 
        self.rows[r1], self.rows[r2] = self.rows[r2], self.rows[r1]
```

This function is also used in Gauss elimination, hence the search for a pivot column if no pivot row is found, which is logically not required for Bareiss.